# Mysql Error in remote server. But working fine in my local machine

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (9999999-1000000+1)+1000000) as random_number 
WHERE "random_number" NOT IN (SELECT number 
                              FROM random_numbers) LIMIT 1;
```

In above script working fine in my local computer. But not working in the remote server. What can be affected to this situation. 
If there any alternative please suggest.

Note: the server is a Linux server

Comment: remove double quotes around random_number and use backticks. Are MySQL server version(s) same in your local computer and remote server ?

Comment: No if i remove the quotes there is an error, Unknown column 'random_number' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: You cannot use a expression defined in the select clause, in the where conditions. Because where is executed first, then select.

Comment: But this is working fine in my local machine. Server Version is "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper" and my local machine version is "mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)"